# Visual studio connection properties issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

Since a few days, I'm having strange behavior, when I want to debug a project:
It always opens the connection properties window, although I have no database connection set up in that project.

Maybe this problem occurs because I set up another project with azure?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude the file from your project.

Try this:

To temporarily exclude an item that represents a file
--> In Solution Explorer, select the item you want to exclude.
--> On the Project menu, select Exclude From Project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But which file should i exclude?

Comment: I guess the one that asks for the database details.

Answer (score 0):

In your  project open up the `Properties` tab, and there probably is a `Publishprofiles` folder. Delete it. Afterwards, open up the `Web.config` file in the project. See if there is any `<connectionString>` tag and delete them all if you dont have database connections.